# K&R 1-7 is it solvable by using putchar() instead of printf?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

There are many questions about this exercise all over the internet, but I couldn't find any solution (nor any hint) on how to solve this exercise using 'putchar'.

```
Write a program to print the value of EOF.
```

I can easily get a working answer to this:

```
printf("%d", EOF);
```

I'd like to know if there are any known (or logical) answers using 'putchar' (as I guess that was the whole purpose of the exercise, being located at the end of a paragraph on 'getchar' and 'putchar')

Writing:

```
putchar(EOF);
```

or

```
int c;
c = EOF;
putchar(c);
```

the program just launches and closes itself without showing any text.

Comment: a character is printed here... But I'm not sure to understand what result you are expecting here. The value of EOF is an integer (-1 usually).

Comment: Perhaps you should use `putchar` to write the *decimal* value of EOF.

Comment: _Why_ do you feel the need to "use `putchar`" here?

Comment: Spoiler: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11975780/1025391

Comment: @ Jongware treating EOF as a float just returns some gibberish @Lightness _Races_in_Orbit I asked just to make sure (as I wrote, the exercise is presented in a section about putchar)

Comment: But "numerical" does not automatically imply "float"! (Although you may be doing something wrong. The usual value of EOF, `-1`, is a *perfectly fine value* for a float as well.)

Comment: Here are a few examples using different types in printf: `%d` -> `-1`; `%f` -> `1.#NAN0`; `%s` -> [void]; `%x` -> `ffffffff`

Comment: declaring c to be `int`, `double`, `long`, `short`, `float`, `char` and then equationg c to the value of EOF all lead to an empty output

Comment: sorry, equating (`==`) c to `EOF` gives `int` -> `Ç`; `long` -> `Ç`; `short` -> `@`; `float` -> [void]; `char` -> [void]

Comment: (the last two comments meant "declaring c and then calling it with putchar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putchar` converts its argument to `unsigned char` before it's outputted (and it's a character which is written, not the result of a decimal conversion). As `EOF` is negative, this conversion isn't value-preserving. Commonly, `EOF` has the value -1, with 8-bit `char`, that conversion results in 255, that is, `putchar(EOF)` is equivalent to `putchar('\xff')`, which isn't a printable character (assuming an ASCII system). Piping the output to `hexdump -C` would make the output visible.

Without using `printf` and friends, a function outputting a decimal number for an `int` can be written. Basically,

```
print a '-' if the value is negative
for every decimal digit, starting from the highest-valued:
    convert the digit's value to a character (e.g. 7 should become '7')
    try to print the result (with putchar, for example)
    if that fails, return an error indicator
```

Hint: The division and modulus operators, `/` and `%`, will be useful.

The digits `'0'` ... `'9'` are ascending (and contiguous); so for the conversion from the digit's value to a character, adding `'0'` yields the desired result (`3 + '0'` is `'3'`, for example).

Care must be taken to avoid integer overflow, even if corner cases like `INT_MIN` are passed to the function. `-INT_MIN` may result in an overflow (and in fact does on pretty much every system), a positive number, on the other hand, can always be negated. A value of 0 may need special handling.

(Alternatively, the number can be converted to a string first which then can be outputted. A `char` array of size `1 + sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3+1 + 1` is big enough to hold that string, including minus sign and 0-terminator.)

If you get stuck, the (non-standard) `itoa` function does something similar, looking for example implementations may give some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` is not a char which can be printed as you expected. So `putchar(EOF)` doesn't print any values, as it prints only `char`.

Hence use `printf("%d", EOF)` which outputs integer `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) of `putchar()`,

> `int putchar(int c);`
>
> `putchar(c);` is equivalent to `putc(c,stdout)`.

and

> `putc()` is equivalent to `fputc()` .......`fputc()` writes the character `c`, cast to an `unsigned char`, to `stream`.

This, `putchar()` is supposed to output the `char` representation of the ASCII value supplied as it's argument.

So, if the value of `EOF` is a non printable character [in ASCII], you won't see anything [*"without showing any text*"] on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

`putchar(int char)` So if you pass a ASCII value to this API you get a corresponding character printed on the screen but `EOF` evaluates to -1 which is not a printable ASCII character so you don't see anything or might see some junk.